# Failing to borrow from Aave's Lending Pool

Tags: solidity, flash-loans, aave

I'm trying to borrow USDC from Aave v2's lending pool through an interface, but I can't manage to do it:

My contract:

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import './interfaces/MyILendingPool.sol';
import './interfaces/MyIERC20.sol';


contract FlashLoaner {

    struct MyCustomData {
        address token;
        uint256 repayAmount;
    }

// **** storage variables from the proxy ****
    address public logicContract;
    address public deployer;
    uint public borrowed;
// ********  
  
    function execute(address _weth, address _contract, uint256 _borrowed) external {

        MyILendingPool lendingPoolAAVE = MyILendingPool(0x7d2768dE32b0b80b7a3454c06BdAc94A69DDc7A9);

        MyIERC20 weth = MyIERC20(_weth);

        address usdc = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48;
        uint aaveUSDCloan = 1000000 * 10 ** 18;

        weth.approve(address(lendingPoolAAVE), _borrowed);

       lendingPoolAAVE.deposit(_weth, _borrowed, _contract, 0);

       lendingPoolAAVE.borrow(usdc, aaveUSDCloan, 2, 0, _contract);  //---> issue
    }
}
```

The interface is well connected and I managed to successfully deposit some collateral (6400 ETH) using `deposit()`.

When I query from `MyILendingPool` using -and commenting out `borrow()`-:

```js
function getUserAccountData(address user)
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint256 totalCollateralETH,
      uint256 totalDebtETH,
      uint256 availableBorrowsETH,
      uint256 currentLiquidationThreshold,
      uint256 ltv,
      uint256 healthFactor
    );
```

...I get all the correct values, and a `availableBorrowsETH` of around 15M USD (converted).

The error that I get is:

`Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Delegate Call failed'`

...since this is the logic contract from a proxy where I `delegatecall()`, but I don't think that the issue is on the proxy, since when I comment out `borrow()` and just query from the Lending pool, everything runs smoothly.

Thanks for the help!

Just in case, `MyILendingPool`:

```js
// // SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface MyILendingPool {

    function deposit(
    address asset,
    uint256 amount,
    address onBehalfOf,
    uint16 referralCode
  ) external;

  function borrow(
    address asset,
    uint256 amount,
    uint256 interestRateMode,
    uint16 referralCode,
    address onBehalfOf
  ) external;

  function getUserAccountData(address user)
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint256 totalCollateralETH,
      uint256 totalDebtETH,
      uint256 availableBorrowsETH,
      uint256 currentLiquidationThreshold,
      uint256 ltv,
      uint256 healthFactor
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AAVE v2 USDC and USDT tokens use 6 decimals rather than 18. My guess is that you are trying to borrow a trillion million dollars rather than just a million.

This line:

`aaveUSDCloan = 1000000 * 10 ** 18;`

should probably be:

`aaveUSDCloan = 1000000 * 10 ** 6;`

Documentation on decimals used by the different atokens here:
https://docs.aave.com/developers/deployed-contracts/deployed-contracts